# Is there an option to run automatically a specific pre-commit hook on all the files, even if they have not been modified?

Tags: pre-commit.com

My usecase is quite specific: I have a file containing a version and several other files of the project need to have the same embedded version.

The idea is to have a pre-commit hook that check these other files and eventually update them at commit time.

Please note that it works fine with `pre-commit run --all`, but I would like to automate it when the `git commit` command is run.

As far as I understand, only the modified files of the repository are passed to the executable of the hook. The unmodified ones are skipped.

My .pre-commit-config.yaml file looks like:

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/degauden/euclid-pipeline-hooks.git
    rev: 1.0.0
    hooks:
    -   id: dependency-version-fixer
        always_run: true
```

If I modify the version in my CMakeLists.txt and run a `git commit`, I get:

```
Dependency Version Fixer.................................................Passed
[develop d7bd259] Move to 1.5
```

Which is not what I expect.

If I run a `pre-commit run --all`, I get the expected result:

```
Dependency Version Fixer.................................................Failed
- hook id: dependency-version-fixer
- exit code: 1
- files were modified by this hook

Fixing SLE_IAL_Pipelines/auxdir/SLE_Detection_Pipeline/PkgDef_SLE_Detection.py
Fixing SLE_IAL_Pipelines/auxdir/SLE_Modeling_Pipeline/PkgDef_SLE_Modeling.py
```

How can I have the 2 python files fixed by a `git commit` if they have not been modified (are not in staged state I guess)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what have you tried, what isn't working

Comment: I have tried:

---
-   repo: https://github.com/degauden/euclid-pipeline-hooks.git
    rev: 1.0.0
    hooks:
    -   id: dependency-version-fixer
        always_run: true
---

But it only changes the requested files with `pre-commit run --all` and not with a plain `git commi`

Comment: This is the first time that I post on stackoverflow and I don't know how to format my comments correctly. Sorry.

Comment: Hi @anthonysottile. You are right about the fact that bumping the version is not a very good idea. But I don't have much choice since the underneath language is CMake, and it makes the situation far more complicated if I try to interpolate the needed files. But I have my answer: use the `pass_filenames: false` and browse the source tree with python. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your premise is kind of a bad one -- needing to update every file all the time always is a mess and is going to balloon your git repo size.

you probably want to store the version in one place and use your programming language's import mechanism to share it instead.

auto-bumping versions as part of the commit is also a bad idea because there's no good way to undo it.

if you *really* want this bad behaviour make your tool discover every file and do it that way -- the framework intentionally doesn't support something like what you want.  you can do something like `git ls-files -z` and then iterate through it in your script.  in that case you'd want to set `pass_filenames: false` as well such that pre-commit doesn't try and run it on the particular files that are changed

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit